# Table of content spacing in beamer with column

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am using beamer to prepare my presentation and everything was working fine but the table of contents slide. The margin was too small for this slide so I put it inside a column.

However, doing that also changes the space between the items of the table of contents and I do not understand why. The same behaviour is observed using a minipage.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
     \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
     \begin{columns}
     \column{10cm}
           \tableofcontents
     \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Sec 1}
\frame{test}
\section{Sec 2}
\frame{test}

\end{document}
```

[image: Unusual behaviour of toc in beamer]

Is there a way to set the spacing to be the same? Or, if this is not possible, a simpler way to change the margin for the table of contents alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to adjust `\leftskip` inside the frame

Beamer redefines `\tableofcontents` (more precisely `\addcontentsline`) to add glue between the toc entries, but to expand glue you need a given height to fill, which is why columns doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
     \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   \addtolength{\leftskip}{2cm}%
   \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Sec 1}
\frame{test}
\section{Sec 2}
\frame{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I see why it behaves this way now. Also, very simple solution, I like it!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the margins using `\newgeometry`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
     \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\newgeometry{hmargin=2cm}
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\restoregeometry

\section{Sec 1}
\frame{test}
\section{Sec 2}
\frame{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the newgeometry command. I will keep it in mind! :D